# Retrieve multiple values from XML in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am trying to retrieve multiple values of  and store in a list.
In my Code string value is equal to this data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2008/07/excelservices/rest" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservice" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">Part_Number</title>
  <id>http://test.net/excel/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/docs/abc.xlsm/Model/Ranges('Part_Number')</id>
  <updated>2015-04-07T16:23:43Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <link rel="self" href="http://test.net/excel/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/docs/abc.xlsm/Model/Ranges('Part_Number')?$format=atom" title="Part_Number" />
  <category term="ExcelServices.Range" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
  <content type="application/xml">
    <x:range name="Part_Number">
      <x:row>
        <x:c>
          <x:fv>Part Number</x:fv>
        </x:c>
      </x:row>
      <x:row>
        <x:c>
          <x:fv>LBL-61641-000</x:fv>
        </x:c>
      </x:row>
      <x:row>
        <x:c>
          <x:fv>HDW-61277-001</x:fv>
        </x:c>
      </x:row>
    </x:range>
  </content>
</entry>
```

C# Code

```
List<string> lirangeName = new List<string>();
string value = GetRangeValue1("abc.xlsm", lirangeName[0]);  //Value contains the above xml value
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(value);
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2008/07/excelservices/rest");
string answer = doc.SelectSingleNode("//x:fv", nsmgr).InnerXml;
```

Here, string answer = Part Number. So, I get 1 value but I want a list of values.

```
Answer I want :
Part Number
LBL-61641-000
HDW-61277-001

Answer I get:.
Part Number
```

Comment: If you hadn't guessed already, `SelectSingleNode` selects a single node... what was your expectation of how that would behave?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML for this sort of thing - it's much simpler, particularly around namespace handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the list of nodes in the collection, change your last line to the following:

```
var answers = doc.SelectNodes("//x:fv", nsmgr);

if (answers == null)
    return;

foreach (var item in answers)
{
     var result = ((XmlNode)item).InnerXml;
}
```